# Virtual Backgrounds Not Rendering Properly: Seeking Guidance on WebRTC Implementation

Tags: javascript, canvas, segmentationselfie

I am working on integrating virtual background support into a video calling application using the RobustVideoMatting library ([GitHub Repository](https://github.com/PeterL1n/RobustVideoMatting)). The segmentation of the foreground is successful, but I am facing a challenge with the background rendering during WebRTC streaming, i am not able to apply background image to the segmented video.

**Methods Tried:**

**Method 1 - CSS Styling:**

```
const bg = `url('${this.bg}') center center / cover`;
this.canvas.style.background = bg;
```

**Method 2 - HTMLImageElement:**

```
const backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = "https://d..........................jpg";
backgroundImage.onload = () => {
    canvasRef.current.getContext("2d").drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, 640, 480);
}
```

**Request for Assistance:**

I am seeking guidance on resolving this issue. If anyone has experience with virtual backgrounds and WebRTC, or if there are specific considerations when using the RobustVideoMatting library, your insights would be greatly appreciated.

**GitHub Repository:** [PeterL1n/RobustVideoMatting](https://github.com/PeterL1n/RobustVideoMatting)

**CodePen Link** [CodePen Reference](https://codepen.io/Nicola-Haines/full/xxexeXm)

Need to apply the background image or video to the segmented video frames.